# 3rd Gen (2001) 4Runner - Radio won't turn on after new install

Tags: toyota, audio, 4runner

I just installed a new radio in my 3rd gen (2001) 4Runner and it won't turn on.  Thing's I've tried:

- Re-installing the old radio.  It also no longer receives power
- Visually checking radio harness for wiring issues.  I have not tested with a multimeter (don't own one).
- Checked the ACC fuse and the DOME fuse
- Switched the security toggle hidden in the driver side foot well
- Turned key to on, pressed the red security button, turned key to off

These are all of the suggestions I was able to find online and none of them have led to the stereo turning on.  Any other suggestions?

There are many reports of similar issues here, though no solution other than to use a different power source: https://www.toyota-4runner.org/3rd-gen-t4rs/80478-removed-stock-radio-now-doesnt-work-3.html

Comment: Check all the fuses. You might get lucky and find one which has gone out to lunch.